# Team Explorer 2008 won't install on Win 7 64 Bit with VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, team-explorer

I am trying to install Team Explorer on Windows 7 64 bit.  Everytime I run the installer, it errors out, and i find the following in the log:

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode): ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Component Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) returned an unexpected value.
```

Not sure how its returning an error when that is what is suppose to be being installed (and no, its not already there)

I tried patching VS, but no good.  Could it be because I don't do a default install?  (I like to remove the non c# langauges and other options I know I won't use)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, apparently even though I have admin access to my machine, Team Explorer for 2008 didn't think so (VS 2005, 2008, SQL 2008, and VS TE 2005 all installed without complaint).  I just ended up right clicking and choosing 'Run as administrator'